# Traveling wave equation derivation from free space electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Following my textbook I came across this derivation. I can make the assumption in 3.11 that solving ODE will give you $e^{jkx}$. But I get lost in the substitutions and assumptions being made in 3.12. Can anyone explain those steps.

[image]

Comment: Stick $\psi(x)=Ce^{jkx}$ into the time-independent Schroedinger equation to find the expression for $k$. And the time-dependent exponential will have been explained previously in your book (look for 'separation of variables').

Comment: Just out of curiosity what text is it? Must be oriented to electrical engineers in areas that use QM.

Comment: @paisanco electronics materials course that all computer engineers at our school need to take. It's from [here](http://www.mheducation.ca/highereducation/products/0073104647&pNumber=918991/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation 3.11, which is also called time-independent Schroedinger equation,  is derived from the original time dependent Schroedinger equation, which is a partial differential equation, by separation of variable, assuming that the solutions can be written as a product of a function that depends only on t and another function that depends only on x. This gives two ordinary differential equations, one for the time dependent function having the solution exp(-jt) with E= h, and one, which is equation 3.11, for the x-coordinate dependent function which has the exp(jkx) solutions. Therefore, in order to obtain the complete solution of the time dependent Schroedinger equation you have to multiply the t-dependent and the x-dependent functions giving the exp j(kz-t) travelling wave solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Given

$$\psi(x) = Ce^{jkx}$$

if we take the second derivative we get

$$\frac{d^2 \psi(x)}{d x^2} = -k^2Ce^{jkx}$$

So substituting into equation 3.11 on both sides, we get

$$\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}Ce^{jkx} = ECe^{jkx}$$

which gives

$$k= \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}$$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this but how is the e^j(kx-wt) part reached?

Comment: Start with the time dependent Schrodinger equation in 1D and separate variables, it should come right out in similar fashion.